# The term to describe linear algebra's $\textrm{general solution }=\textrm{particular sol. + homogeneous sol.}$ in group theory

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to relate the idea that in linear algebra any solution set $S$ of a given system of linear equation $Ax=b$ and $Ax_0=b$ then $S=\{x_0+k\mid k\in \ker A\}$, to some corresponding idea in group theory. So far I only know that if the kernel is used to divide the domain of a given homomorphism then the same image corresponding to the same coset of kernel. Please help if this is not a wrong question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f: G_1 \to G_2$ is a homomorphism of groups, then the set of solutions of $f(x)=b$ is $x_0K$, where $K=\ker f$ and $x_0$ is a particular solution.

Comment: Since only one operation is needed in my question so it's considered group, not ring right?